# Cosmetics: Make up, make-up, or makeup?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

When referring to cosmetics, which is correct? Make up, make-up, or makeup? And does it matter in case of a noun, verb, adjective?

> The actor playing Frankenstein's monster wore 6 pounds of [makeup |
> make-up | make up].
>
> The [makeup | make-up | make up] professional applied 6 pounds of
> cosmetics to the actor.
>
> Go sit over there, and she will [makeup | make-up | make up] your face
> for you.

Comment: Any user of writing software knows that this question has defeated even the geniuses behind Word.  If I had £10 for every time I enter (say) the words "make up" separately and get a red squiggly line, only to get another red line when I put "make-up" instead, I could afford a very expensive luxury cruise by now.  All I can tell you is that my sense is that the verb "make up" is not hyphenated, while the 'noun' normally would be hyphenated.  Check a good dictionary.

Comment: **Makeup** the noun (and the attributive noun that acts like an adjective) is one word. *The monster wore six pounds of makeup applied by the makeup professional.* **Make up** the verb is two words. *The makeup professional will make up the monster's face.* See [makeup](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/makeup).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: No... [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/makeup), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/makeup), and [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/makeup). In any case, one should consult one's style guide regarding which dictionary to use.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat But CED, Collins, Macmillan and AHD all list both solid and hyphenated forms for the compound noun. As you point out. As they indicate, there is probably a US / UK divide here, but both forms are legitimate.

Comment: I would not consult a dictionary on such a matter. I’d look at ads and help columns. A dictionary is inherently behind on such matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately all of them are valid:

[lengusa | makeup](https://lengusa.com/search/makeup)

[lengusa | make up](https://lengusa.com/search/make%20up)

[lengusa | make-up](https://lengusa.com/search/make-up)

However '**makeup**' is only used in cosmetics context so I would suggest you to use '**makeup**'.

Even **Encyclopedia Britannica** uses '**makeup**' version.